# Admob Phonegap doesn't work

Tags: cordova, admob

I am trying to add Admob on my phonegap application, but he doesn't work, I don't know why :/

```
function domLoaded(){
 alert("loaded");
 var IS_APP = document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 &&   document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1;
 var ad_units = {
 ios : {
   banner: 'ca-app-pub-6944053263628084/2993763855', // votre référence  fournie par AdMob pour cette application
   interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6944053263628084/5947230254' // votre référence fournie par AdMob pour cette application
 },
 android : {
   banner: 'ca-app-pub-6944053263628084/9994470251', // votre référence fournie par AdMob pour cette application
   interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6944053263628084/3947936653' // votre référence fournie par AdMob pour cette application
 }
};
// le code s'adapte en fonction de la platforme
var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;

if(IS_APP && AdMob) { // on vérifie que c'est un mobile et que AdMob est bien chargé
if(Math.floor(Math.random()*5) === 1) { // 1 fois sur 5 on affiche l'interstitial
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {
    adId:admobid.interstitial,
    autoShow:true}
  );
}
else {
  AdMob.createBanner( { // 4 fois sur 5 la bannière
    adId:admobid.banner,
    position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    autoShow:false,
    overlap:true}
  );
  }
 }

 //AdMob.showInterstitial(); // pour afficher la pub interstitial précédemment chargée
 // pour afficher la bannière publicitaire précédemment chargée
 //AdMob.hideBanner();
 AdMob.showBanner();
}

function showBanner(){
}
```

Here's my 'Pub.js'

the alert("loaded") works good, when I call domLoaded()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  domLoaded();
});
```

I've make "phonegap local plugin add.admob.google"

and I've had 
in my config.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469049/admob-integration-for-phonegap-doesnt-show-the-advertise

Comment: the valid admob plugin id is: com.google.cordova.admob, and you can directly copy the sample index.html to your www/ for testing: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I test a lot of differents integration of this plugin and it finally works yesterday. 
I'm using Cordova with Ionic Framework and ngCordova (AngularJS) normaly but it'll work in a normal cordova installation :)

My solution : 
1 - Install the plugin as you are used to, using CLI for example then just :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function( ) {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    /* Admob stuff */
    if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
      adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx', 
      position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
      autoShow: true } 
    );

  });
})
```

That is the beginning of my app.js file. These few lines under the Admob comment are enough :) above it's just about ionic structure.
Remember to try on a real device or emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i you can add the ad Code like so

```
function adSetter(){
alert(navigator.userAgent);
var admobid = {};
// select the right Ad Id according to platform
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1657046752'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
    };
}

if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId:admobid.banner, 
    position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
    autoShow:true} );

}
  function onDeviceReady(){
  alert("device ready");
      adSetter();
  }


function domLoaded(){
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

The code goes from bottom to top.
I have used alerts to make it easy for testing on a device

here is the full source:

http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-banner-ads-to-phonegap-apps-using-admob-pro-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to execute the code under onDeviceReady.

Complete implementation:

```
<html><head><title>Device Ready Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// Wait for device API libraries to load
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    domLoaded();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, 
Madan

Comment: Is not the same think as $(document).ready(function(){
  domLoaded();
}); ??

Comment: No its not the same. Code inside deviceready ensures that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

Answer (score 0):

From the javascript code you paste, I guess you are attempting to use my AdMob plugin: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Then your command "phonegap local plugin add.admob.google" is wrong.

The valid admob plugin id is "com.google.cordova.admob", or "cordova-plugin-admobpro", and using Cordova CLI is a better choice.

So, the valid command to add plugin is:

```
cordova plugin add com.google.cordova.admob
```

Or (if Cordova v5.0+, plugin registry is being migrated to npm, and plugin name rule is changed):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Any issue when using this plugin, please create issue tracker in the project homepage at GitHub. I will be glad to help.