# Admob integration for phonegap doesn't show the advertise

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I'm experimenting with the Admob plugin for Phonegap but it is complex. I have this code but it doesn't show the advertise and I really don't know why.. Can you guys see something wrong in the code? Yes I imported the plugin.

http://pastebin.com/zbEs6D7H

Comment: A quick start to use the plugin is to run the sample file, see: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro#quick-start-with-cordova-cli

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova (`cordova plugin add com.admob.google`)  you should wrap your code with deviceready event:

```
function configAds() {
  var enabledAdMob = true; // easily enable/disable AdMob
  ...
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", configAds, false);
```

See complete phonegap example here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-demo